# How would I add code that would update an online "counter" so I know how many times an iPhone app is being opened?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

So I have searched for this but not finding anything about it and if I missed it sorry about that. What I am trying to do is see how to go about adding some code to my iphone app that will connect to a php script (if connection available) and update a counter so that I can let my clients know that their app is constantly being used? Also, would apple allow that? Or would my app be denied for doing such a thing? Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bit of network plumbing to implement this. It's not hard, but a much easier route would be to integrate something like Flurry analytics into your app. They you can make one function call, and have it track and upload the information to Flurry's servers. You can view those stats and get an idea of how people are using your app.

Note: I don't work for Flurry, but I use (and like) their service.

Comment: In addition to Flurry, there's also Google Analytics: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/mobileAppsTracking.html , which many people will be familiar with from their website analytics.

Comment: nice! thank you for introducing me to this. this is exactly what I was looking for and more.

LT